# Automatic copy a row when a certain value is given

Tags: google-sheets, copy, row

I need to automatically copy a row when a certain value is given.

With `Moveto` it works, but with `copyto` it does not.

Can someone help me?  tx

```
function myFunction3() {

    var sheetNameToWatch = "Planning";
    var columnNumberToWatch = 12;
    var valueToWatch = "Running";
    var sheetNameCopyTheRowTo = "Facturatie";

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getActiveCell();

    if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch 
       && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch
       && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) 
    {
          var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
          var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
          sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(targetRange);   
    }
}
```

Comment: the 'range' is undefined in your code in range.getcolumn syntax and are you getting any errors with copyto?

Comment: Inside the `if `statement when you say `range.getColumn()` etc I think you meant `rangeToCopy.getColumn() ` etc. So suggest fix that for starters, as pointed out by shabnam bharmal.